# XML to XSL what do I do wrong

Tags: xml

I'm trying to publish some data from an XML report from our firewalls on a webpage. Since the data in the XML will be updated from time till time I can't just publish the data static.

Now I have spent some time to look into the XML and on the web but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

a part of the XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet href="test.xsl"
    type="text/css"?>
 <report reportname="top-application-categories">
   <result name="Top application categories" logtype="appstat" start="2017/02/08 00:00:00" start-epoch="1486508400" delta="86400" slabbed-     start="2017/02/08 00:00:00" end="2017/02/08 23:59:59" end-epoch="1486594799" slabbed-end="2017/02/08 23:59:59" generated-at="2017/02/09 00:00:16" generated-at-epoch="1486594816" range="Wednesday, February 08, 2017">
<entry>
  <category-of-name>general-internet</category-of-name>
  <nsess>14765605</nsess>
  <nbytes>81973979657</nbytes>
</entry>
<entry>
  <category-of-name>business-systems</category-of-name>
  <nsess>8449911</nsess>
  <nbytes>2747818255111</nbytes>
</entry>
<entry>
  <category-of-name>networking</category-of-name>
  <nsess>7673706</nsess>
  <nbytes>172508825988</nbytes>
</entry>
```

Now I tried to create an XSL which makes sure only the Category-of-name, Nsess and Nbytes are shown on the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" 
   omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
   indent="yes" 
   standalone="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="report">
     <xsl:element name="report">
     <xsl:for-each select="result">
     <xsl:element name="result">
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
           <xsl:element name="entry">
              <xsl:attribute name="category-of-name">
                 <xsl:value-of select="category-of-name"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="nsess">
                 <xsl:value-of select="nsess"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="nbytes">
                 <xsl:value-of select="nbytes"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
           </xsl:element>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

I found this example on the WWW at MSDN. It explained how to use XML and display the data on an webpage created in Visual Web developer.
Still tried that been there same result, or an error or it just displays nothing at all.

Hopefully someone can steer me in the right direction :)

Comment: Try this out first an XML editor like Oxygen XML Editor using the debugger. Then if you get the results, go and attach it to the webpage. This way you would be sure the xsl is working.

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 5. In your result name="Top application categories" tag there's an an unsetted slabbed- attribute.

It leads you to an not well formed XML error. You can use http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator in order to check if it's well formed and valid online.

I hope that It helps you ;)

Comment: Do you mean the <result ? that it is not closed by </result>?. Because it is I just pasted the top of the report :)

Comment: No, inside the open result tag you have this : start-epoch="1486508400" delta="86400" slabbed-     start="2017/02/08 00:00:00" end="2017/02/08 23:59:59". Between start-epoch and start attribute you have slabbed- that  is not set. Anyway if you try to check in  the online validator it gives you the line and all form errors.